# awk and sed tab seperation. How to add third tab?

Tags: windows, bash, awk, sed, wireshark

In a previous question I asked about the syntax for awk and sed in Windows. This now works, but I have another question (which you hopefully will and can answer).

PS: Sorry for all these questions, but I am still very inexperienced with using awk and sed.

The following script will output 2 tabs, one showing the time in seconds and the second showing the bytes per second.

```
Wireshark\tshark -r WireShark\dumps\combinedOutput2.pcapng -T fields -e  frame.time_relative -e frame.len 
        | sed -e "s/\...*\t/,\t/" 
        | awk -F"\t" "$1==last {sum += $2; next}
{ 
printf(\"%s  %8d bytes/s \n\",last,sum,sum*8/1024/1024); 
last=$1;sum=$2
}" > test.csv
```

Output:

```
10993,       135 bytes/s
10994,        54 bytes/s
10995,       135 bytes/s
10996,        54 bytes/s
10997,       135 bytes/s
10998,        54 bytes/s
10999,       135 bytes/s
11000,       199 bytes/s
```

Now I would like another tab on the right with the destination IP address (ip.dst), comma delimited. When I try to put another tab in the script it gives me errors.

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You just have to add another parameter in your `printf` ---> `printf(\"%s  %8d bytes/s %s\n\",last,sum,sum*8/1024/1024, another_thing);`

Comment: In Windows always put your awk scripts in a file and execute as `awk -f script.awk` to avoid having to deal with Windows' nightmarish quoting rules.

Comment: Don't apologize for asking questions, there is nothing wrong with it. Remember that posting the errors you get will be useful for the ones trying to answer.